# Why is there no ExpectedConditions method that returns Boolean for element visibility?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Why is there no ExpectedConditions method that returns Boolean for element visibility?  For example, there is a **Boolean** "invisibility of AND staleness of" method but not "visibility" and "present"?  Why?  Are we expected to use the **not** method?

```
boolean invisible = wait.
  until( ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated( locator ) );

boolean unpresent = wait.
  until( ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf( locator );
```

There are only 2 workarounds for this that I can think of:

```
boolean found = wait.
   until( ExpectedConditions.not.invisibilityOfElementLocated( locator ) );
```

And this one is my preferred workaround (since, in this case, my FluentWait does not need to ignore the ElementNotFoundException):

```
boolean found = false;
List<WebElement> foundElements = wait
  .until( ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy( locator ) );
found = foundElements.size() > 0;
```

Wouldn't it make sense that there would be a direct "visibility of" method in the ExpectedConditions class (that returns **Boolean**; not just WebElement) or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that the `ExpectedConditions` developers wanted to limit the size of the API, so instead of creating two `visibilityOf` methods for each type, one that returns `boolean` and one that returns `WebElement`, they created only one that either return `WebElement` or throws `TimeoutException`.

Why `visibilityOf` returns `WebElement` and `invisibilityOf` returns `boolean`?

In `visibilityOf` you can use the element you were waiting for or ignore the returned value. But when you wait for `WebElement` to disappear you can't realy do anything with it, so why return it? not to mention this condition expect for the element to be invisible or *not present in the DOM*.

By the way, `ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy` will either return `List` with size greater then 0 or throws `TimeoutException`. The check `foundElements.size() > 0` won't work.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense in retrospect.

Answer (score 0):

Why is there no Boolean test for visibility as opposed to invisibility?

My guess is that this is done to encourage more efficient coding and to take advantage of how all Selenium locators already work.

All selenium locators work by returning a list of elements that meet given conditions on a page.

Invisibility cannot rely on the standard locator code because success can come from elements not being present at all.  We cannot guarantee an ability to return a web element based on this and are forced to supply a boolean result instead.

Presence, visibility, enabled, etc. can all return the element found and reduce overhead of multiple callbacks by giving the user the element without further processing.  This is a good thing for fast code. I believe the developers intentionally optimize for this case and did not supply a boolean test to encourage its use.

```
WebElement found = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout)
  .until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated((By)loc));
```

While it would have been possible to use standard locator code to return elements that were hidden, this is much more fragile.  It is common for later optimizations to remove elements in a case like that.